# .htaccess qualifier issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Does anyone know what the problem is with this rewrite rule?

```
RewriteRule ^example/?(.*)/?(.*)/?(.*)$ example.php?id=$1&ud=$2&ed=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Shouldn't it work by detecting `?` as a conditional?

**Edit** OK, let me rephrase my question.

How do you get Apache to ignore `$1` - `$3` if it's empty, and just instead go to example.php?

For example, instead of 3 lines:

```
RewriteRule ^example/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ example.php?id=$1&ud=$2&ed=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^example/(.*)/(.*)$ example.php?id=$1&ud=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^example/(.*)$ example.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I need one line to solve all 3 or more.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you're trying to achieve.  Can you give specific examples?

Comment: For example it would not phrase pass then first (*) and regardless of "example/a/b/c" it would only phase to "example.php?id=a&ud=&ed=" in another word, i have no idea what's going on?

Comment: It seem it phase it as ?id=a/b/c instead.....

Comment: Did it work with my one line?

Answer (score 1):

Greediness considerations make your rule equivalent to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^example/?(.*)$ example.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You probably want this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^example/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ example.php?id=$1&ud=$2&ed=$3 [QSA,L]
```

---

Based on the recent edit you did to your question, I'd use multiple rules:

```
RewriteRule ^example/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ example.php?id=$1&ud=$2&ed=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^example/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ example.php?id=$1&ud=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^example/([^/]+)/?$ example.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: does it detect if it's empty and ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

The 404 error could be caused by a missing RewriteEngine. To solve the problem with the parameters, use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^example/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?$ example.php?id=$1&ud=$2&ed=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: how is it it keep giving me error 404? it's like it does not recognize and phase it?

Comment: I updated the regex. I have tested and verified that it functions as expected with example.php printing out $_GET on my PHP server.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't it work by detecting ? as a conditional?

Sure, but backreferences are still filled in order. If the first parentheses `(.*)` match the empty string, then `$1` is empty; there is no way to make this capture get "skipped".

Comment: so you are saying there is no such thing as "if($1 is empty) Skip id=$`"?

Comment: because my htaccess is like 1k line long because of this and it's a bit slow even with litespeed htaccess cache features.

Comment: @Poppy: No, you may not embed a conditional statement into the result URI.

Comment: @Poppy: Actually, if you wanted to be really complex, [you could pass the translation off to Perl with the `prg` MapType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), but then you might as well just keep it relatively simple and use multiple rules.